# Step into c++/CLI wrapper dll and c# dll during debug while making plugins on firebreath

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, c++-cli, firebreath

Building a firebreathplugin where there's a native dll, c# class library dll and a c++/CLI (class library) wrapper dll. No application here. Saw other posts on stack overflow. Did the Debugging Mixed mode .but in vain?
**UPDATE**

```
1.  in c# dll properties I have "Enable unmanaged code debugging" unchecked 
2. in c++/CLI wrapper dll properties, I have set Debug mode as mixed and set Attach to Yes
3. in native c++ plugin dll (firebreath generated) I set Properties->Debugging>Debug Mode->Mixed and Attach as "Yes"
```

COMPILER for c++/cli wrapper dll is /clr and for the native c++ is set "no /clr support"
USING LOCAL WINDOWS DEBUGGER for this
To debug the plugin i just followed the step described in firebreath homepage(i.e.click Debug menu and then Attach to process..i selected the iexplore.exe)
Hope I would get an answer soon?

Comment: Are all dlls/exes compiled with the same VS version, in the same configuration and platform?

Comment: Yes @stijn Sir! vs 2010

Comment: "Debugging Mixed mode".  Describe what you did in detail.  Look at the "Modules" window--do you see both native and managed dlls in the list?

Comment: @Matt Smith Yes i see both modules in the properties of the native c++ plugin dll

Comment: @PratikPattanayak, not sure what you mean by "in the properties of the native c++ plugin dll".  Once you're attached, go to Debug->Windows->Modules, and see if all the expected dlls show up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those settings matter **unless** one of those projects is the Start-up project (i.e. the one in bold in the solution explorer).  The settings of the start-up project is what matters.

Or, if you'd rather not change the start-up project, then you can do an "Attach to Process" and specify what types (Managed, Native, etc).

Comment: I would be running the plugin by attaching to a process of a browser @Matt Sir. So that browser is my startup. don't u think?In my plugin dev. soln. there's no startup project Sir.

Comment: @PratikPattanayak, So, you are attaching to the browser using Debug->Attach to Process?  And if so, where it says "Attach to:" what does it say?  You can set this to the appropriate types you want to debug by pressing the Select button.

Comment: I know, so I did the same...by selecting the browser iexplore.exe's  process after pressing Debug->Attach to .I was just saying about the option "Attach" which is set as YES. The Attach option can be found in the project's propertie->Debugging->Attach.

Comment: @PratikPattanayak, You didn't answer my question: When you do Debug->Attach to process, where it says "Attach to": what is listed?  The Attach option you are talking about is *meaningless* unless (a) you start debugging directly from Visual Studio (which you are *NOT*) and (b) the project is the Start-up project (which it is *NOT*).

Comment: agreed. I forgot to write Attach to Process in the question!Ya selected iexplore.exe from the process list. I know there's no start up project.so have u found a fix yet?Thanx for reverting by the way

Comment: @PratikPattanayak, I can help you more once you answer the question I've asked you twice now.

Comment: The "Attach to Process" dialog box comes up and about mid way down there is a label that says "Attach to:" then to the right it has a button that has "Select...".  Show an image of your "Attach to Process ".

Comment: I can't my reputation is low..but i got what u need. the options listed are>>>1. Managed(v 2.0,v1.1,v1.0) 2. Managed(v4.0) 3.Native 4. Script 5. T-SQL 6. Workflow ..all are unchecked. and I have the option  "Automatically determine the type of code to debug" selected @ Matt Smith

Comment: Okay, you'll want to check Managed (v4.0) and Native.  (I'm assuming you're targetting .NET 4.0).

Comment: ..Hi again..how to go past this error..error C1190: managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option while building my plugin dll? I have already set the compiler switch to "no clr support"  for the plugin dll.  any clue?

Comment: @PratikPattanayak, post a new question with all the details.

Comment: @Matt..for some reasons, I hvae been banned!Somebody downvoted me one question

Comment: @PratikPattanayak Downvoting doesn't mean you're banned (it just means someone thought it was not a well formed question).  You can still ask new questions.  Just make sure to include all the appropriate details in your question, and be sure to ask a single well directed question (rather than vague open ended questions).  Good luck.

Comment: this the message I get>>"Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more..."

Comment: @PratikPattanayak, looks like you'll need to follow the tips on how to get the automatic ban lifted.  Good luck.